# use function names in perl's map

Tags: perl, syntax, subroutine, chr

I was playing with this piece of code to print a list of chars:

```
perl -e 'print join(" ", map { sprintf "%02x", ord }  grep /\s/, map { chr } 0x0 .. 0x7F )'
```

Is there a easier way to write `map { chr } 0x0 .. 0x7F` ?

I've tried:

```
map \&chr 0x0 .. 0x7F
```

But I get syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map { chr } 0x00 .. 0x7F` is already pretty concise, but in addition to the `map BLOCK LIST` syntax, there is also the `map EXPR,LIST` syntax.

```
map chr,0x00..0x7f
map chr,0..127
```